# Cloned Domain Controller Couldn't Start

Tags: active-directory, esxi

I cloned 3 DC (Windows 2016) on a ESXi host for a lab test purpose. All 3 DCs are on an isolated network and can reach each other. However, the active directory failed to start. Whenever I tried to start the Active Directory User and Computer, it threw an error saying "Naming information cannot be located because the specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted".

I used to do the same thing on windows 2008 domain which worked just fine.

I reckon something's changed on Windows 2016 that affected the clone DC from running normally. Any has experience on this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you sysprep this system before cloning it?

Comment: No. But the source DCs are production DCs, hence I don't want to run Sysprep on it. and if I understand it correctly, Sysprep prevents duplicate SID in the environment, but I'm cloning all three DCs to create an identical (but on isolated network) environment as production. thanks!